# Bash Script For FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

trying to write simple script to encode files but keep getting this error msg:

/usr/bin/cm: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
/usr/bin/cm: line 28:`else'

and here is the script called cm:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Filename?
read Filename
echo Enter Target Filesize In Megabytes..
read TargetSize
echo ffmpeg preset?
read PRESET
Duration='ffprobe -i $Filename -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"'
Bitrate='($TargetSize*8192)/$Duration'
exiftool -b $Filename -ImageSize
echo WIDTH=?
read WIDTH
echo HEIGHT=?
read HEIGHT
echo Padding Required? Enter 'y' or 'n'
read PADANSWR
if [PADANSWR = 'y'] then
echo X=?
read X
echo Y=?
read Y
ffprobe -show_entries stream=index,codec_type:stream_tags=language -of compact $Filename -v 0 | grep eng
echo ENG AUDIO INDEX?
read ENGAUDIOINDEX
echo ENG SUBS INDEX?
read ENGSUBSINDEX
ffmpeg -i $Filename -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset $PRESET  -b:v $Bitrate -vf "padding=width=$WIDTH:height=$HEIGHT:x=$X:y=$Y:color=black" pass 1 -f matroska /dev/null -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k && ffmpeg -i $Filename -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset $PRESET  -b:v $Bitrate -vf "padding=width=$WIDTH:height=$HEIGHT:x=$X:y=$Y:color=black" -pass 1 -f matroska ENCODE1.mkv -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k
else
    ffmpeg -i $Filename -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset $PRESET -b:v $Bitrate -threads 12 -pass 1 -f matroska /dev/null -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k && ffmpeg -i $Filename -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset $PRESET -b:v $Bitrate -threads 12 -pass 1 -f matroska ENCODE1.mkv -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k
fi
```

just started coding in bash--how long can the lines in a script be or do i need to use the '\' character--if i do use the '\' character does it need a space after it? TIA

Comment: Not proficient in Bash, but try indenting the `then` block.

Comment: You need a semicolon before 'then'. You're probably better off asking questions like this on stackoverflow, since the issue is with the programming, rather than anything to do with video.